# ActiveAdmin custom filter causes Ransack error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, ransack

I have a ActiveAdmin column that I would like to filter by as a string. However when I enter this code on /app/admin/user.rb (the page where I would like the filter):

```
  filter :name, as: :string
```

I get the error:

```
undefined method `name_contains' for Ransack::Search<class: User, base: Grouping <combinator: and>>:Ransack::Search
```

I'm struggling to figure out the right Ransack code to put in /app/models/user.rb  which will enable me to do this. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: This question/answer can be helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39756673/custom-filter-in-rails-activeadmin-using-ransack