# Custom filter in rails ActiveAdmin using ransack

Tags: filter, activeadmin, ransack

I have created an activeadmin filter that has the following choices on filtering the table data in its drop-down menu.

Choice A

Choice B

Choice C

Choice D

I want to add a fifth choice F that would either choice B or C (that is the results of both B and C).

Choice A

Choice B

Choice C

Choice D

Choice F = either B or C

The choices are stored in a table called Coupons in its title field (i created a row having the choice F). So far, I tried to employ a ransack to do the trick, without being quite sure.

```
//app/admin/user.rb
filter :has_right_choice, label: 'Filter by the right choice', collection: Coupon.all, as: :select

//app/models/user.rb
ransacker :has_right_choice, :formatter => ->(title) {
   if (title == 'Choice F')
      Coupon.all.where("title = 'Choice B' OR title = 'Choice C'")
   else
      Coupon.all
   end

 } do |parent|
 parent.table[:id]
end
```

But my solution doesn't work. Is there a better approach instead of ransack ? If not, any suggestion ?

==========================================================================
**EDIT: solution**

Choice A # lets say that this choice has id = 1 in Coupons table

Choice B # id = 2

Choice C # id = 3

Choice D # id = 4

Choice F # id = 5

Also lets say that Users table has a field choice_id that refers to the Choices table.
We modify the faulty code as follows:

```
//app/admin/user.rb
filter :choice_id_in, label: 'Filter by the right choice', collection: Coupon.all, as: :select


//app/models/user.rb
  ransacker :choice_id,
            :formatter => -> (coupon_id) {
              if (coupon_id == "5")
                  ids  = User.all.where("choice_id = 3 OR choice_id = 4").map(&:id)
              else
                  ids = User.where("choice_id = ?", coupon_id).map(&:id)
              end
              (ids.empty?) ? ids << 0: ids #activeadmin translates the queries into IN operator, may get syntax error if empty
                    # id = 0 is non-existent in Users as id >= 1
              ids #maybe is not needed
              } do |parent|
  parent.table[:id]
  end
```

Suggestions for improvement are welcome. Thanks @berker for the guidance.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "my solutions doesn't work"? Do you get errors? Wrong results? E.g. you could show the database-queries that it results in and why they are wrong.

Comment: Wrong results. No matter what I choose, all the rows are retrieved. Before doing the modifications this would not happen. Probably I'm missing something but cannot figure out what.

Comment: please have a look in the `logs/development.log` and extract the logged sql query that now yields the wrong result. Paste that in your answer, so we have an idea how the SQL is going wrong.
In addition, place some debugging at `title == ` and in the else, to see what the values are at that point and in which part of the if-else you end up when choosing `F`.

Comment: Hello @berkes. I have put a syntax error in both branches of if-else-end and it seems that this code is not covered. Also my development.log is approximately 500M .. no clue how to search it. I tried fgrep but the output is too large to be helpful.

Comment: What i try to do and did not mention it (because i think there is no point in) is that I'm using this guy's suggestion: http://codeonhill.com/activeadmin-custom-column-and-its-filter/

Comment: Finally I found the solution to this. I will edit the post asap if someone else wants to do the same. Thanks again!

Comment: `rake log:clear` to clear the logs. `tail -F log/development.log` to follow it. When you are running `rails server` the logs are printed to screen by default. It is of utmost important to learn to read and interpret these when troubleshooting a Rails project.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me